# Data structures with monads

Tags: haskell, monads

```
import           Control.Monad
import           Control.Monad.Random        as MR
import           Control.Monad.ST
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed         as VU
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as VUM
import qualified Data.Vector                 as V
import qualified Data.Vector.Generic         as VG
import           Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable as VGM
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed         as VU


data Obj m = Obj
    { aNum :: Int
    , vec  :: m (VU.Vector Int)
    }

instance Show (Obj m) where
   show Obj{ aNum = a
           , vec = v
           } = show a ++ show v -- 'show v' not OK

main :: IO()
main = do
  rVec <- evalRandIO (randVector 5) -- OK
  obj <- evalRandIO (newObj 1 5) -- Not OK
  print $ show rVec
  print $ show obj

newObj :: (MonadRandom m) => Int -> Int -> Obj m
newObj aNum' vecLen = Obj aNum' $ randVector vecLen

randVector :: (MonadRandom m) => Int -> m (VU.Vector Int)
randVector len = randSample (VU.enumFromN 0 len) $ VG.length vec

-- Fisher-yates shuffle
randSample :: (MonadRandom m, (VG.Vector v a)) => v a -> Int -> m (v a)
randSample vec len = do
  let getR i = do
          r <- getRandomR (i, (VG.length vec)-1)
          return (i, r)

  swaps <- mapM getR [0..len-1]

  let vec_rands = runST $ do
          vec_mut <- VG.thaw vec
          forM_ swaps $ \(i, j) -> do
              VGM.swap vec_mut i j
          vec_rands' <- VG.unsafeFreeze vec_mut
          return vec_rands'

  return $ VG.take len vec_rands
```

I'm having some trouble creating data structures with monads. In particular, the data structure contains a random vector and some other fields which are not random. Using `evalRandIO` works when the whole type is a monad but not when just some part of the data structure is a monad.

I get the feeling that I should use `fmap` or something of the sort, but they give different errors. I also have some trouble converting a random vector to string in order to print it to screen. I'm unsure of the difference between `Rand g` and `MonadRandom m`, and which one I should use. The latter seem to work but all examples online seem to use `Rand g` instead.
Furthermore. general code review is also appreciated.

> ```
> * Couldn't match type `Obj m1'
>                  with `RandT StdGen Data.Functor.Identity.Identity a0'
>   Expected type: Rand StdGen a0
>     Actual type: Obj m1
> * In the first argument of `evalRandIO', namely `(newObj 1 5)'
>   In a stmt of a 'do' block: obj <- evalRandIO (newObj 1 5)
>   In the expression:
>     do { rVec <- evalRandIO (randVector 5);
>          obj <- evalRandIO (newObj 1 5);
>          print $ show rVec }
> ```

Comment: `m (Vector Int)` is not a vector or data structure. Why do you have that `m` in there?

Comment: If I don't I get type-errors when calling `randVector` in `newObj`

Comment: `newObj n vecLen = do { vec <- randVector vecLen; return (Obj n vec) }`

Comment: So using the do-notation kinda moves the MonadRandom out to top level?

Comment: Correct. A rather handwavy rule: As long as you're dealing with data structures, you don't want `m Anything` as function parameter or as part of a data structure. `m` should only appear in the result of actions such as `newObj` or `randVector` (and you can locally remove `m` by using `<-` within a `do` block).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
newObj     :: (MonadRandom m) => Int -> Int -> Obj m
newObj 1 4 :: (MonadRandom m) =>               Obj m
evalRandIO ::                                  Rand StdGen a -> IO a                                    
evalRandIO (newObj 1 4) :: -- ?????????
```

The problem is that `Obj m` isn't `Rand StdGen a`. Therefore you cannot use `evalRandIO`.

However, it doesn't really make sense to put the `m` inside `Obj`. It's possible, but not really handy. We could fix your code if we've used

```
evalObj :: Obj m -> IO (Int, (VU.Vector Int))
evalObj (Obj a mvec) = do
   uvec <- evalRandIO mvec
   return (a, uvec)
```

But that's still not easy to use. Instead, let us simplify `Obj`:

```
data Obj = Obj { oNum :: Int, oVec :: VU.Vector Int } deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Now let's rewrite `newObj`, so that it returns `m Obj`:

```
newObj :: (MonadRandom m) => Int -> Int -> m Obj
newObj num len = Obj num `fmap` randVector len

-- alternatively, but does the same:
newObj num len = do
   vec <- randVector len
   return (Obj num vec)
```

And everything is fine. This also makes it possible to use your `Obj` in functions that don't know that you operate in a `MonadRandom`, e.g.

```
sqObj :: Obj -> Obj
sqObj (Obj a v) = Obj (a * a) (VU.map (^2) v)
```

Comment: Regarding the last point. Is that only possible when an `m Obj` has been bound inside a monadic function? If not then how do I know that a function does not know that it operates in `MonadRandom`? Because I can't seem to be able to remove `MonadRandom m` from the type signature of `randVector`, even though the function itself does not use anything from `MonadRandom`.